# Commitlog incremental switch

Tags: cassandra

We get a burst of  'No segments I reserve; creating a new  one'in log,as soon as we start our performance  burst run on a single node cassandra Cluster.
Presumably, this means the commit log is expanding to grab more segments;which would impact the performance metrics.
Questions on the above:

```
1.Can this be avoided by pre-reserving segments for commit log and how.  
2.How can we query the current limit of a commitlog for a cassandra instace.  
3.We also notice memtable flush pointing to commitlog activity. Does commitlog sync duration  trigger table flushes
```

We are using version 3.11.x

Comment: How much does it impact your performance metrics? I have never seen it be a problem before.

Comment: We are measuring the incremental impact of disk flush on a small data write burst - by  attempting to begin with a 'no-flush' scenario

Comment: are you using batch mode? rate of disk flushing shouldn't impact write throughput at all unless the sync time exceeding 1.5* periodic interval.

Comment: So memtable to disk flush is not in the critical path of throughput but asynchronous?I did not understand the point about sync time though - any reference literature will help.

Comment: the periodic commitlog mode will by default only flush every 10s, not every request, and writes are appended during that time. For single node durability you need to use batch mode. Usually people rely on higher CL for durability vs the single instance durability - but where its absolutely critical use group or batch mode. By default though, the commitlog flush will not block writes unless the flush takes 1.5* the periodic interval - which is why I asked on what impact your seeing in performance metrics since its not really expected to have any.

Comment: The most confusing point in cassandra discussions seems to be whether cassandra flushes block writes,and thereby impact write throughput or not.What's the correct answer to this?my own tests seem to show that flush doesn't block write